# What is the correct way to use TypeForwardedToAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I came across to this attribute in [this post](http://en.csharp-online.net/TypeForwardedToAttribute) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/TypeForwarding-CLR.aspx). It seems that it's very useful when we need to upgrade an old system. Then I create a test solution(with 3 projects in it) in order to use this attribute. Firstly there is a class library project named "Animal".

```
namespace Animal
{
   public class Dog
   {
      public static string Name = "old version";
   }
}
```

Then I create a console application project, add "Animal" as a reference, and in the `Main` method I have:

```
Console.WriteLine(Animal.Dog.Name);
```

Now it prints "old version". Great! Now I begin to "upgrade" the existing project. I remove the class `Dog` in "Animal" add another class library project named "AdvancedAnimal" which contains:

```
namespace Animal
{
   public class Dog
   {
      public static string Name = "new version";
   }
}
```

Add "AdvancedAnimal" as a reference in "Animal". Also `AssemblyInfo.cs` of "Animal" is modified by adding:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(Animal.Dog))]
```

From the usage of this attribute, from now on all `Animal.Dog` is forwarded to the `Dog` class in "AdvancedAnimal"(actually there is no `Dog` class in Animal any more). I re-compile the whole solution and hope the console application prints "new version". But it gives me a compile error:

`The type name 'Dog' could not be found in the namespace 'Animal'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'AdvancedAnimal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.`

Oh, I'm told to add "AdvancedAnimal" as a reference to my console application! But if I do so, I don't need the attribute any more, because if I add "AdvancedAnimal" as a reference in the console application, of course `Animal.Dog` refers the one in "AdvancedAnimal"! What I expect is that modifying "Animal", Adding "AdvancedAnimal", no necessary to change all other projects/class libraries because the assembly info already provides enough information. That is really convenient when upgrading a system. Otherwise, I have 20 projects referring to "Animal", I need to add "AdvancedAnimal" as a reference to all of them. And more important is, I can't find any usage of "TypeForwardedToAttribute" in this solution, removing it doesn't matter anything. Can you tell me what's wrong with my test/idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [the documentation for `TypeForwardedToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute):

> Use the `TypeForwardedToAttribute` attribute to move a type from one assembly to another without disrupting callers that compiled against the old assembly.

But what you are doing is forwarding the type from the same assembly to another type in the same assembly. It doesn't make any sense.

Lets make it clear. Assume if you have a class dog in assembly oldAssembly.dll

```
namespace Animal
{
   public class Dog
   { 
      public void printName() {      
           console.writeline("old version");
      }
   }
}
```

and referenced it in some other assembly (x.dll)

```
   Dog dg=new Dog();
   dg.printName()
```

later you wanted to change the printName functionality, but without touching the caller (x.dll) (assume if the dll is deployed and dont want to be touched)

so you create a new assembly (dll), which got

```
namespace AdvancedAnimal 
{
   public class Dog
   { 
      public void printName() {      
           console.writeline("new version");
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can now recompile the old dll by adding reference to the new dll and adding

```
[assembly:TypeForwardedTo(typeof(AdvancedAnimal.Dog))]
```

Now whatever calls made to the Animal.Dog forwarded to AdvancedAnimal.Dog.

So

> ! What I expect is that modifying
>   "Animal", Adding "AdvancedAnimal", no
>   necessary to change all other
>   projects/class libraries because the
>   assembly info already provides enough
>   information. That is really convenient
>   when upgrading a system. Otherwise, I
>   have 20 projects referring to
>   "Animal", I need to add
>   "AdvancedAnimal" as a reference to all
>   of them.

You dont have to add AdvancedAnimal to all your 20 projects. All you have to do is adding AdvancedAnimal to Animal.

Hope this clarifies the context where it can be useful

**EDIT:**

> I re-compile the whole solution and
>   hope the console application prints
>   "new version". But it gives me a
>   compile error:

Whole point of this is we can call a new assembly without modifying the caller. You should not recompile the whole solution, because your caller is still pointing to the method int the old assembly. That's why you got the error

> The type name 'Dog' could not be found
>   in the namespace 'Animal'. This type
>   has been forwarded to assembly
>   'AdvancedAnimal

Just recompile your old & new assemblies and put it into the caller bin and run the exe. It'll work like a charm.

Comment: "But what you are doing is forwarding the type from the same assembly to another type in the same assembly", no. two assemblies, "Animal" and "Advanced Animal".

Comment: But the namespace remains "Animal", because in one of the post the author says we can't change the namespace here.

Comment: What I did is exactly what you told me to, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Ramesh: Got it! No need to re-compile the console application! The original `.exe` file outputs "new version". I'm trying to compile the console application a whole day and it's keeping giving me compile-errors. LOL!

Comment: If this is how it works, this attribute is essentially useless. Just because you don't _need_ to recompile the external assembly  to get the benefit of the now-intermediary assembly redirection shouldn't mean you _cant_ ever recompile the external assembly.

Comment: @StingyJack, maybe a real-world use case will help clarify. `System.Action` was added to the `System.Core` assembly in .NET 3.5, but then in .NET 4 it was moved to the `mscorlib` assembly with a type forwarder added to `System.Core`. By adding that type forwarder, a dll compiled against .NET 3.5 using this type can be loaded into a .NET 4 application.

Comment: sure, but if you had to recompile something that had referenced System.Core and had moved, then the attribute doesnt work. You have to change all the references to now use mscorlib. Its a big time sink compared to what was expected.

Comment: @StingyJack: 1) Recompiling would only fail if you started compiling against the new version 2) Type forwarders don't support changing the namespace, so fixing the compile time issues is typically a matter of adding a reference to the new assembly 3) if you move the type from `assembly-A` to `assembly-B` where `assembly-A` is dependent on `assembly-B`, then `assembly-B` is probably already going to be referenced and no code changes are necessary (assuming you don't reference the types via an assembly alias.)

Comment: Namespaces must be preserved when moving a type.  That's because .NET knows your types by their full name.  Simply keeping the class name is not good enough.  Using the attribute you can simply move the code for the type, preserving full name across to another assembly.  Sadly you cannot rename the type.

Comment: @user195275 So to clarify, you're saying that this answer, as currently written, *doesn't work*, since it isn't possible to forward all uses of `Animal.Dog,old.dll` to (renamed) type `AdvancedAnimal.Dog,new.dll`, right?  Assuming the same namespace must also be preserved at the new location, the [fully-qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names) of the moved type would then end up being `Animal.Dog,new.dll`, yes?

Comment: Not really, because dotnet allows you to have full type names completely unrelated to assembly name. So it would still be possi me to rename the assembly while keeping the old namespaces in the new assembly and have the forwarding to them.  What you cannot do is rename assembly and rename types (namespaces too) while moving them.

Comment: @user195275, what Glenn is saying is that, in this answer, the new type is in a different namespace than the old type (`Animal.Dog` vs `AdvancedAnimal.Dog`), and thus it would not work with type forwarding. Can you confirm? Can the OP update his post to make it correct?

Comment: Confirmed.  Namespaces must remain same.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I've heard about that attribute, interesting :)

The way I read the documentation, the attribute can be used in scenario's where you're only delivering a set of library dll's.

Let's say you have some application, that uses a set of widgets from a DLL. Later on, you decide to move parts of that DLL to a separate DLL. Using the `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, you can do that by having the old DLL reference the new one. You can now deploy both DLL's to the installations of the existing application, *without recompiling the application itself*

This could be useful in scenario's where you don't have control over the application itself, but are merely supplying a set of library dll's. In order for your codebase to move forward, you can use the `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, and have users deploy it safely to their application, without breaking anything.